# Can't send HTTP post request in my wanted format

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I want to send a post request but I don't know how to send the data in the way I need it.

The data of the request when I sniff should look like this only(because it looks like this when I sniff while I am using the website):

[username, password]

but I don't know how to send it differently from the format of JSON: username=name&password=pass

Here is what I tried, but it didn't work.

```
    postdata = ["victor", "asdasd"]
    resp = requests.post(SERVER_IP, data=postdata)
```

I expect it to send the data as I wrote but I got an error that said: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: `postdata` must be a JSON object:) [doc](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)

Comment: `postdata = {"username": "victor", "password" : "asdasd"}`

Comment: So can't I send a http request with a data that looks like this: ["name","password"] becuse  the website that I am using accepts only this format

Comment: If I will send it like this: postdata = {"username": "victor", "password" : "asdasd"} it will look like this username=victor&password=asdasd   but the website accepts only when it looks like this: ["victor","asdasd"]

Comment: You can try this: `postdata = {'id': ['victor', 'asdasd']}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to encode `postdata` as bytes:

```py
postdata = ["victor", "asdasd"]
resp = requests.post(SERVER_IP, data=str(postdata).encode())
```

data can be a bytes objects, as per the docstring:

```
 :param data: (optional) Dictionary, list of tuples, bytes, or file-like
        object to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
```

Comment: Now I see that your solution also have a problem, the server will not accept using ' and not "